# Flutter: Select Card inside GridView

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, gridview

I have an app which displays data in Cards inside GridView like so:

```
GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: <Widget>[
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: image1, item: item1, price: price1, count: count1
            ),
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: image2, item: item2, price: price2, count: count2
            ),
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: image3, item: item3, price: price3, count: count3
            ),
            _customCard(
              imageUrl: image4, item: item4, price: price4, count: count4
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I want to get the specified card name when it is pressed depending on its index inside a List as we do in ListView.

```
 class item {
  final String name;
  final int count;
  final String imageUrl;
  final double price;

  item({this.name, this.imageUrl,  this.count, this.price});
}

List<item> tops = [
  new item(
      imageUrl: "tshirt.png",
      name: "T-shirt",
      count: 0,
      price: 0.50
  ),
  new item(
      imageUrl:   "shirt.png",
      name: "Shirt",
      count: 0,
      price: 0.80
  ),
```

Is there a way to do so with GridView or shall I try something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Gridview.builder` and use its `index` to get the related object from list:

```
return GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: _customCards.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
         return Inkwell(child:_customCards(
          imageUrl: image[index], item: item[index], price: price[index], count: count[index]),
          onTap(){
            print(tops[index]);
           }
        ),
        }
        );*
```

Comment: Thank you it worked as I wanted..I appreciate your help